# Allow access to specific pages

Tags: symfony4, symfony-security

I am on Symfony 4.3.2, trying to get a way to allow users having role (CommissionOwner) access to only specific pages.

- Users having role other than 'CommissionOwner' can access all pages.
- Users having role 'CommissionOwner' can access only following pages.

  - www.xyz.com/Loginlandingpage
  - www.xyz.com/reportSalesCommissions

I am trying in  **myApp/config/packages/security.yaml**

```
access_control:
     - { path: ^/reportSalesCommissions, roles: IS_CommissionOwner }
```

Answer (score 1):

Every role name should started with: **ROLE_**

So if you declare your role as **ROLE_COMMISSION_OWNER**

you can create properly role hierarchy and access_control in your security config

It should be something like this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/reportSalesCommissions, roles: ROLE_COMMISSION_OWNER }
    - { path: ^/loginlandingpage, roles: ROLE_COMMISSION_OWNER }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER: ROLE_COMMISSION_OWNER
```

Comment: No it didn't work, Users having role other than 'CommissionOwner'  cannot access page '/reportSalesCommissions'. And also this user can access other pages by hitting a url in browser.

Comment: @AbdulGhaffar ok, now everything is more clear. I'm also edited my answer.